# How to generate contours around a mesh with modifiers?

Tags: modifiers

I am making a shoulder armor easily editable. I want to keep the original flat mesh and generate the golden contour like you can see on this image by using modifiers:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that can be done with modifiers alone

Comment: @Danyl Bekhoucha have you considered a (subtle) displacement through an image? Depending on desired result also some boolean trick could be used perhaps. Not sure but... maybe.

Comment: A displacement image would require UVs.